# Override values.yml using helm extension for ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, ibm-connections, kubernetes-helm

I want to create a playbook for installing external helm charts provided by ZIP archive from IBM. Its required for us to override some values from values.yml by custom ones (e.g. host to docker registry.

Example from IBMs values.yml

```
image:
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: artifactory.swg.usma.ibm.com:6562
```

Since a non public repo was set by IBM, I uploaded the images (downloaded from IBMs releases) to my custom registry `registry.example.com` and want to set it in my playbook:

```
- name: CNX Bootstrap
  helm:
    # Port forwarding from tiller to localhost
    host: localhost
    state: present
    name: bootstrap-test
    namespace: "{{namespace}}"
    chart: 
      name: bootstrap
      source:
        type: directory
        location: /install/component-pack/IC-ComponentPack-6.0.0.7/microservices_connections/hybridcloud/helmbuilds/bootstrap
    values: 
      image.repository: "registry.example.com"
```

This doesn't work, the pod logs say:

> Failed to pull image "artifactory.swg.usma.ibm.com:6562/bootstrap:20190204-022029": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get https://artifactory.swg.usma.ibm.com:6562/v1/_ping: Service Unavailable

So it's still using the wrong registry and my custom `values` seems to be ignored. Using `helm` cli, I'm able to override using `--set` switch like this:

```
helm install --name=bootstrap /install/component-pack/IC-ComponentPack-6.0.0.7/microservices_connections/hybridcloud/helmbuilds/bootstrap-0.1.0-20190204-022029.tgz --set image.repository=registry.example.com
```

#### How can I override the chart's values like the `--set` switch does in Ansible?

The [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/helm_module.html) doesn't provide any information. I only [found out](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/3fcc564bbb079cbf0aea949438d4d9148acf2171/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/misc/helm.py) that [pyhelm](https://github.com/flaper87/pyhelm) is used. But I couldn't find a way to override the default values.

Answer (score 5):

When PyHelm gets the values passed from your Ansible chart definition it is passed as a dictionary, which it converts to a yaml. Tiller (the server side component of Helm) expects the values yaml passed to remain nested. Thus, you need to store them as a nested dictionary in your Ansible definitions.

In your case, it would look something like:

```
- name: CNX Bootstrap
  helm:
    # Port forwarding from tiller to localhost
    host: localhost
    state: present
    name: bootstrap-test
    namespace: "{{namespace}}"
    chart: 
      name: bootstrap
      source:
        type: directory
        location: /install/component-pack/IC-ComponentPack-6.0.0.7/microservices_connections/hybridcloud/helmbuilds/bootstrap
    values: 
      image:
        repository: "registry.example.com"
```